# why doesn't priorityQueue require comparable interface at compile time?

Tags: java

The following code is legit to pass compilation.  Why can PriorityQueue be defined to only take elements that is instanceof Comparable?

```
...
PriorityQueue<Object> q = new PriorityQueue<Object>();
q.add(new Object());
...
```

But it throws the expected exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast     to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:595)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:591)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:291)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:268)
    at ReentrantLockExample.main(ReentrantLockExample.java:12)
```

Answer (score 5):

Because it *also* allows you to specify your own `Comparator` for element types that aren't `Comparable`.  This also affects `TreeSet`, `TreeMap`, and basically all other sorted collections.

If you're trying to avoid it in your own code, prefer factory methods to constructors, since you can specify different type constraints on different factory methods.  For example, Guava [provides](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html)

```
<E extends Comparable> TreeSet<E> Sets.newTreeSet();
<E> TreeSet<E> Sets.newTreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're allowed to store objects that don't implement `Comparable`, *as long as you provide a `Comparator`*.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a `Comparator` provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used. A priority queue does not permit `null` elements. A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in `ClassCastException`).